# Подсчет уникальных значений в двух столбцах без UNION

Tags: sql, hql

Имеется таблица `Deal`. В ней есть два поля: покупатель `Buyer` и продавец `Seller`. Пользователь в сделке может быть быть как покупателем, так и продавцом. Надо посчитать количество уникальных партнеров (контрагентов) по всем сделкам за один запрос.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03035/39).

Проблема в том, что мне это надо сделать на HQL, который очень похож на SQL, но не поддерживает `UNION`.

Или хотя бы объединить или вытянуть в один столбец и продавца и покупателя. А подсчет уникальных значений уже можно и в коде сделать.

Есть временное решение через два запроса, которого хватает при низкой нагрузке, но хочется красивого решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `CASE` (для выбора партнёров), `DISTINCT` (для выбора уникальных значений) и `HAVING` (для отсечения значения `NULL`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE Buyer WHEN 'a' THEN Seller
    ELSE CASE Seller WHEN 'a' THEN Buyer END END AS 'partner'
FROM Deal
HAVING partner IS NOT NULL
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c71bc/1).

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой хак - замена union join'ом. Создаете временную таблицу с одним столбцом и двумя записями, например, 1 и 2.
Делаете декартово произведение таблиц (cross join) и case'ом выводите Buyer, если поле=1 и Seller если 2.

[примерно так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fddfc/3)

Answer (score 0):

[Как объединить данные из двух столбцов в один без использования UNION и JOIN?](http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select14.php)

Comment: Ответ-ссылка - это нехорошо. Добавьте описание решения в сам ответ.